# How to declare a received parameter as a global variable in a decision table

Tags: java, drools

I don't know if the thought of my question is correct but basically, I'm passing a `java.util.Map` to a decision table and I wish to access its values in any part/cell of the excel decision table. I'm thinking of something like this:

[image]

I'm planning that when a condition is true, its action will update a certain key-value pair by pulling the value from another key-value pair of the same map that the decision table received. I thought that maybe declaring it as a global variable might solve the problem but I can't seem to go around how to do that.

**UPDATE:**
Adding the error message I receive when I'm trying the approach above. Please take note that `someKey` has been replaced by `SUPPOL`. That's why its in the error message below:

[image]

Comment: Changes to global variables aren't like changes to a static variable in Java. It's much easier to make the change to an object in working memory and then call update to refire the rules.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yeah I realize that. But because of a design that we're trying to follow, I can't change the object that I'm throwing in to the decision table. I'm trying to exhaust all possibilities that I come up with

Comment: You're not going to see changes to the global object. It's just not going to work.

Comment: Rereading your question, if you want to make changes to the passed-in map and make the changes visible to other rules, you just need to call `update($map)` after making the change. (where $map is the map you've passed in). This will cause all rules to be re-evaluated.

Comment: I did use that before but based on the example I gave, it seems that the `map` or maybe the `map.get` is not recognized in cell C10

Comment: What does "is not recognized" mean?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'll add the error message on my update